# Foursquare venues api returns incorrect data for checkin intent

Tags: foursquare

It varies from city to city but I've noticed that the actual Foursquare app always returns an accurate list of stores that are nearby for checkin ... whereas the developer api results are mostly inaccurate and often upto 3 blocks off their mark when usin intent=checkin ... what gives?

Comment: Perhaps it's the accuracy of your `ll`/`radius`? I'd also imagine that up to 3 blocks is a tolerable error—we're talking feet here, not miles!

Comment: I don't think that `radius` applies to checkin mode. I've also wondered about the accuracy of `ll` but there is a standard way of calculating it, which we all get from Apple samples, so there's nothing magical about that. Unless the 4square app itself runs some sort of refined algorithm that averages out 3~4 different `ll` values before submitting it to the venues api for results? But I can't speak for what their internal app does or does not do. So once again, I wonder what other people's experience with the `intent=checkin` and their own apple-sample-rolled way of figuring out `ll` has been?

Comment: `radius` only applies if you have a `categoryId` or `query`. Can you give a sample request that you're making along with expected/actual results?