# iOS app doesn't fetch same results as Foursquare

Tags: javascript, ios, api, filter, foursquare

I've been wondering for quite a while, I'm using Foursquare's API to use within my iOS app.

It works wonderfully except that fetched results never matches those made by the Foursquare app itself.

I find it very weird, some places aren't even in the list.

Anyone has ever experienced this? Even with the simplest query the results aren't the same.

Is there any docs on how the Foursquare's app handle their filters/requests?

Thanks

edit: I use `venues/search` with `ll` for `lat,lng`.

Comment: I have some recent experience with Foursquare's api used in both iOS and Android and might be able to help. Your question is tagged with Javascript, so I wonder if you're using a webview and your own server, or fetching directly against the REST api. And can you provide an example of a specific request you're sending and specific difference? Thanks.

Comment: Also to add to my previous note, I have experienced what you're saying.  But to inquire about the specific workings of the Foursquare iOS app, is probably going to get you nowhere.  From my perspective, it's simply a (very nice) client like any other, and has no special access that other third-party apps are restricted from. But I can still help you understand what's going on, I expect.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to other parameters that the Foursquare app is passing in. Do you have any specific examples that cause this behavior?

You could also try debugging the Foursquare app through a web proxy. That will show you all the API requests it's making, so you can pin down exactly what's going on. I did a writeup of this technique here: http://nickfishman.com/post/50557873036/reverse-engineering-native-apps-by-intercepting-network

At least you don't seem to be the only one seeing this behavior: [Foursquare venues api returns incorrect data for checkin intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249164/foursquare-venues-api-returns-incorrect-data-for-checkin-intent)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple things that could be in play here.

1) Are you using an authorized token to do your venues/search call from your app? The results of venues/search are personalized based on a user's history and their friends' history.

2) Are you using intent=checkin in your call? The venues/search call done by the Foursquare app does, so the results sent back will be ordered by likelihood that the user wants to check in to a given venue.

3) Are you comparing to the search box in the Foursquare app or to the results of the check-in modal? The search box in the app uses the venues/explore endpoint to do its search, which bakes in a lot more advanced personalization to the results sent back to the device.

Hope those points help clarify what might be going on here!